# Horizontal and Vertical lines on top of img via CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put two lines (horizontal and vertical one) on top of an image via CSS.

here my code:

```css
    div {
       width: 640px;
       position: relative;
    }
    .verticalLine {
       display: block;
       position: absolute;
       background-color: blue;
       width: 3px;
       top: 0px;
       bottom: 0px;
       left: 50%;
       height: 480px;
    }

    .horizontalLine {
       position: absolute;
       width: 3px;
       top: 0px;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 50%;
       background-color: blue;
       transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
```

```html
    <div>
       <span class="verticalLine"></span>
       <span class="horizontalLine"></span>
       <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480">
    </div>
```

Unfortunately my result is: [image: Line Error]

How can I solve this?

thanks

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: your right...ahahahahaha...the horizontal line should go from the beginning of the image til the end

Comment: So like 3 squares? 1 big one and 2 smaller ones which are the same size?

Comment: no, the two lines are drawn in the middle of the image (horizontal at 240px and vertical at 320px), splitting the image in 4 equal parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a height to the `horizontal` line equal to the image width, and then position it in the center with `top:50%`  `translateY(-50%)`.

And also you should add `translateX(-50%)` to both of them to make them stay in the exact center of the image.

See below

```css
div {
   width: 640px;
   position: relative;
}
.verticalLine {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: blue;
   width: 3px;
   top: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 50%;
   height: 480px;
   transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.horizontalLine {
   position: absolute;
   width: 3px;
   top: 50%;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 50%;
   background-color: blue;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
   height:640px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <span class="verticalLine"></span>
   <span class="horizontalLine"></span>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480">
</div>
```

Comment: What if we don't know the height of the img ?

Comment: use `padding-top:100%` instead of `height:100%`

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Comment: you can use the above code and edit it ( in a code snippet or jsfiddle or smth like that ). change `height:640px` with `padding-top:100%` in `horizontalLine ` styles ( in the previous comment i wanted to write `height:640px` not `100%` )

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly....I add another question...if we don't know also the width?

Comment: if we do not know the WIDTH of the img : the WIDTH of the img is used for the height of the horrizontal line. use `padding-top:100%` at horizontalLine instead of `height:640px` . if we do not know the HEIGHT of the image, then at `verticalLine` instead of `height:480px` use `height:100%`